# Issue with module changes in python

Tags: python

I am a newbie to python. Below is my module

mymath.py

```
pi = 3.142

def circle(radius):
    return pi * radius * radius
```

In terminal, I run it following way:

```
>>import mymath
>>mymath.pi
>>3.142
```

When I change pi to a local variable and reload(mymath) and do import mymath, still I get value of mymath.pi as 3.142. However the result of mymath.circle(radius) does reflect the change in result.

```
def circle(radius):
    pi = 3
    return pi * radius * radius

>>import imp
>>imp.reload(mymath)
>>import mymath
>>mymath.pi
>>3.142
>>circle(3)
>>27
```

Can anyone tell me what might be the issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the docs for [`imp.reload()`](http://docs.python.org/3.1/library/imp.html#imp.reload):

> When a module is reloaded, its dictionary (containing the module’s global variables) is retained. Redefinitions of names will override the old definitions, so this is generally not a problem. If the new version of a module does not define a name that was defined by the old version, the old definition remains.

So when you do `imp.reload(mymath)`, even though `pi` no longer exists as a global name in the module's code the old definition remains as a part of the updated module.

If you really want to start from scratch, use the following method:

```
import sys
del sys.modules['mymath']
import mymath
```

For example:

```
>>> import os
>>> os.system("echo 'pi = 3.142' > mymath.py")
0
>>> import mymath
>>> mymath.pi
3.142
>>> os.system("echo 'pass' > mymath.py")
0
>>> import sys
>>> del sys.modules['mymath']
>>> import mymath
>>> mymath.pi
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'pi'
```

Comment: I am just trying to understand why it is not making the changes even after I removed the pi from global scope and defined it as a local variable. I see the result of circle reflecting the change. However mymath.pi is not reflecting the change.
Because in the new code pi is not assigned to 3.142. But instead to 3

Comment: @user1247412 Not sure I follow, did you remove the `pi = 3.142` line from mymath.py before reloading?

Comment: Yes I did remove pi = 3.142

Comment: @user1247412 Ahh, I misunderstood the question.  See my edit (will add more info shortly).

Comment: thank you very much. Is the similar issue exist if I import a module inside other module?

Comment: Why after deleting mymath module, I am able to access mymath.pi. (I did not import the mymath module again). pi is a global variable in this case.

Comment: Did you use `del mymath` or `del sys.modules['mymath']`.  `del mymath` will remove `mymath` from the namespace and trying to access `mymath.pi` should fail.  `del sys.modules['mymath']` will just remove the module from a cache so that on the next import it will reload the code.

Comment: Thanks.. I was trying del sys.modules['mymath'] . It worked with del mymath.